# No puedo actualizar un campo de un formulario Java-Web

Tags: java, jsp, webservice, eclipse

Al momento que quiero modificar un campo del formulario de un registro, en el caso del campo Edad , lo modifico a 19 pero al momento de modificarlo me sale el siguiente error:

```
 GRAVE: Servlet.service() para servlet MisServlets.ServletPaciente lanzó excepción
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at MisServlets.ServletPaciente.actualizar(ServletPaciente.java:98)
    at MisServlets.ServletPaciente.service(ServletPaciente.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Este es el codigo del ServletPaciente (Actualizar):

```
private void actualizar(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PacienteDTO p = new PacienteDTO();
        String cod = request.getParameter("txt_CodPaciente");
        String nom = request.getParameter("txtNombre");
        String ape = request.getParameter("txtApellidos");
        String dni = request.getParameter("txtDni");
        String fechaNacimiento = request.getParameter("txtFechaNacimiento");
        String edad = request.getParameter("txtEdad");
        String sexo = request.getParameter("cbo_sexo");
        String dir = request.getParameter("txtDireccion");
        String correo = request.getParameter("txtCorreo");
        String telefono = request.getParameter("txtTelefono");
        String fechaRegistro = request.getParameter("txtFechaRegistro");

        p.setNombre(nom);
        p.setApellidos(ape);
        p.setDni(dni);
        p.setFechaNacimiento(fechaNacimiento);
        p.setEdad(Integer.parseInt(edad));
        SexoDTO s = new SexoDTO();
        s.setCodSexo(Integer.parseInt(sexo));
        p.setSexo(s);
        p.setDireccion(dir);
        p.setCorreo(correo);
        p.setTelefono(telefono);
        p.setFechaRegistro(fechaRegistro);
        p.setCodPaciente(Integer.parseInt(cod));
        int estado = pacienteService.actualizarPaciente(p);
        if (estado != -1)
            listar(request,response);
    }
```

Este es el codigo que mando la sentencia a la Base de Datos para actualizar:

```
public int actualizarPaciente(PacienteDTO obj) {
        int estado = -1;
        Connection cn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstm = null;
        try {
            cn = MySqlDBConexion.getConexion();
            String sql = "update paciente "
                    + " set nombre=?, apellidos=?, dni=?, fecha_nacimiento=?, edad=?, codsexo=?, direccion=?, correo=?, "
                    + " telefono=?, fecha_registro=? "
                    + " where codpaciente=?";
            pstm = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstm.setString(1, obj.getNombre());
            pstm.setString(2, obj.getApellidos());
            pstm.setString(3, obj.getDni());
            pstm.setString(4, obj.getFechaNacimiento());
            pstm.setInt(5, obj.getEdad());
            pstm.setInt(6, obj.getSexo().getCodSexo());
            pstm.setString(7, obj.getDireccion());
            pstm.setString(8, obj.getCorreo());
            pstm.setString(9, obj.getTelefono());
            pstm.setString(10,obj.getFechaRegistro());
            pstm.setInt(11, obj.getCodPaciente());
            estado = pstm.executeUpdate();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try {
                if (pstm != null)
                    pstm.close();
                if (cn != null)
                    cn.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return estado;
    }
```

Codigo del Formulario ActualizarPaciente:

```
<body>

    <%
        PacienteDTO p = (PacienteDTO) request.getAttribute("pasar");
    %>

<jsp:include page="MenuAdministrador.jsp"></jsp:include><br>
<div class="container">
    <br><br>
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="ServletPaciente?tipo=actualizar" name="frmactualizar" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend style="text-align:center"><label>MANTENIMIENTO DEL PACIENTE</label></legend>
            <fieldset>
                <legend><label>Datos del Paciente</label></legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Código:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled value=<%=p.getCodPaciente()%> name="txt_CodPaciente">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Nombre:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<%=p.getNombre()%>" name="txtNombre">
                        </div>
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Apellidos:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<%=p.getApellidos()%>" name="txtApellidos">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">DNI:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value=<%=p.getDni()%> name="txtDni">
                        </div>
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value=<%=p.getFechaNacimiento()%> name="txtFechaNacimiento">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Dirección:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<%=p.getDireccion()%>" name="txtDireccion">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Teléfono:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value=<%=p.getTelefono()%> name="txtTelefono">
                        </div>
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Sexo:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <select name="cbo_sexo" class="form-control">
                                <%
                                    String sexo[]={"","Masculino","Femenino"};
                                    String estado="";
                                    for(int i=1;i<sexo.length;i++){
                                        if(p.getSexo().getCodSexo()==i){
                                            estado="selected";
                                        }
                                        else
                                            estado="";
                                %>
                                <option value="<%=i%>" <%=estado%>><%=sexo[i]%></option>
                                <%
                                    }
                                %>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Edad:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value=<%=p.getEdad()%> name="txtEdad">
                        </div>
                        <label class="control-label col-md-5">Fecha de Registro:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled value=<%=p.getFechaRegistro()%> name="txtFechaRegistro">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Correo:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value=<%=p.getCorreo()%> name="txtCorreo">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <table align="center">
                        <tr height="30px">
                            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                <a href="ServletPaciente?tipo=listar" target="_self" style="text-align:center">BUSCAR PACIENTE</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr> 
                    </table>
                    </div>

            </fieldset>
            <table align="center" style="border-collapse:separate; border-spacing: 20px">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" name="btnRegistrar" value="REGISTRAR" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" disabled/></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="btnModificar" value="MODIFICAR" class="btn btn-md btn-primary"/></td>
                    <td><a href="Paciente.jsp"><input type="button" name="btnNuevo" value="NUEVO" class="btn btn-md btn-primary"/></a></td>
                    <td><input type="button" name="btnCancelar" value="CANCELAR" class="btn btn-md btn-primary"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" name="btnRegresar" value="REGRESAR" class="btn btn-md btn-primary"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: ¿El dato de `cbo_sexo` es entero?

Comment: si es entero @Garrizano

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código del formulario?

Comment: ya coloque el codigo @Garrizano

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el log completo del error?

Comment: ya lo complete @Garrizano

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49005/discussion-between-garrizano-and-bruno-torres).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifica que todos los datos que envías desde el formulario sean del tipo que reciben. Verifica que por ningún motivo los datos vayan nulos también.

Answer (score 2):

Esto es posiblemente porque el String que estas tratando de leer no es **Entero**, veo que además de Edad, también lo utilizas en Sexo y codPaciente. Hay ocasiones que los campos también traen espacios en blanco. Asegúrate que no traiga espacios en blanco y que sea **Entero**.

La excepción sugiere que el campo no es un número, **NumberFormatException**. Para Integer.parseInt () espera que el argumento sea un número **Entero**.

El Servlet te esta marcando en la línea 98 **ServletPaciente.java:98**, ve a esa línea y ve que campo estas seteando e imprimelo antes de llamar la función.